# How to combine elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm trying to combine the "role" parameter for "Project" objects with the same "id" and "title" parameters in the myProjects array below:

```
struct Project: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var role: String
}

var myProjects = [Project(id: "1", title: "Sunset", role: "2nd AD"),
                  Project(id: "2", title: "Lights", role: "Mix Tech"),
                  Project(id: "2", title: "Lights", role: "Sound Mixer"),
                  Project(id: "3", title: "Beach", role: "Producer")]
var updatedProjects: [Project] = []

// The goal is to update myProjects to show the following:
updatedProjects = [Project(id: "1", title: "Sunset", role: "2nd AD"),
                   Project(id: "2", title: "Lights", role: "Mix Tech & Sound Mixer"),
                   Project(id: "3", title: "Beach", role: "Producer"]
```

This is what I have attempted so far, the result is giving me duplicate combinations of the roles parameter for each project in the myProjects array.

```
var dupProjects = myProjects

for myProject in myProjects {
  for dupProject in dupProjects {
    if myProject.id == dupProject.id {
       let combinedRoles = "\(myProject.role) & \(dupProject.role)"
       updatedProjects.append(Project(id: myProject.id, 
                                      title: myProject.title, 
                                      role: combinedRoles))
    }
  }
}

print(updatedProjects) 
// [__lldb_expr_48.Project(id: "1", title: "Sunset", role: "2nd AD & 2nd AD"),
 __lldb_expr_48.Project(id: "2", title: "Lights", role: "Mix Tech & Mix Tech"),
 __lldb_expr_48.Project(id: "2", title: "Lights", role: "Mix Tech & Sound Mixer"),
 __lldb_expr_48.Project(id: "2", title: "Lights", role: "Sound Mixer & Mix Tech"),
 __lldb_expr_48.Project(id: "2", title: "Lights", role: "Sound Mixer & Sound Mixer"),
 __lldb_expr_48.Project(id: "3", title: "Beach", role: "Producer & Producer")]
```

Comment: Does the order matter, or can you guarantee that the `id`s are in numerical order? Possibly are the `title`s also ordered if they have the same `id`? What happens if the `id` is the same but `title` is different? (impossible case?). Please edit your question with more details

Comment: The order doesn't matter and it's an impossible case for the id and title to be different here.

Comment: The main goal here is to combine the role parameter for "Project" objects that have the same "id" and "title" parameters.

Comment: Are you saying "Assuming I have two arrays, I want to compare them, and from that compare, have an array that is a combination of the two with only unique values. Compared based on ID and Title" ?

Comment: Well, technically I have one array with data, the "myProjects" array. I want to compare the elements in this array, and populate the "updatedProjects" array with the combined, unique values from "myProjects" array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to group them by `id`, combine the roles, then convert the group back to a single `Project`

```
let combined = Dictionary(grouping: myProjects) { element in
    return element.id
}.compactMapValues { projects -> Project? in
    var first = projects.first
    first?.role = projects.map { $0.role }.joined(separator: " & ")
    return first
}.values.map { $0 }
```